# SyntaxError: invalid syntax - defining the argument of the function

Tags: python-3.x, syntax

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FYoY.png)I'm trying to run a function that defines an overlap between the number of words common between two sets. I have a code which is of Python 2.0, I'm trying to replicate the same in Python 3.x:

```
def computeOverlap(self, target, pos, (defn,examples,wordnetints), pre_words, post_words):
        # relevant words = words with same pos
        context_overlap = 0
        def_overlap = 0
        consecutive_overlap = 0

        def_words = defn.split(' ')
        # put all examples into the definition too. # CHANGE. no.
        for example in examples:
            if example.find(target) != -1:
                lst = example.split(target)
                example = lst[0] + lst[1]
                def_words.extend(example.split(' '))
        # put wordnet int senses into defn
        for wnint in wordnetints:
            wnstring = target + "." + pos + "."
            if wnint < 10: wnstring += "0" + str(wnint)
            else: wnstring += str(wnint)
            try:
                wndef = utilities.cleanString(wn.synset(wnstring).definition)
                def_words.extend(wndef.split(' '))
            except: pass
```

When it try to run the function as

```
 #print list_of_senses
        for sense in list_of_senses: # sense is int. length list_of_senses is approx 5
            #print "Senses:\n", sense, list_of_senses[sense]
            overlap = self.computeOverlap(word, pos, list_of_senses[sense], pre_words, post_words)
            #print "overlap for sense", sense, ":", overlap
            #print "!!!!", sense, "Overlap:", overlap
            scores[sense] = overlap+alpha
        #print "Best Sense is: ", best_sense
        if softScoring:
            values = []
            total = sum(scores.values())
            for key in scores:
                scores[key] = scores[key] / float(total)
        return scores, alpha
```

But it's giving me the following error:

```
File "<ipython-input-13-e08e748435b4>", line 91
    def computeOverlap(self, target, pos, (defn , examples, wordnetints), pre_words, post_words):

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Chirag Khandelwal. Please, instead of adding a external image of the error consider adding it in text format. It will make it easier for people to help you. For more information, please take a look at [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Alright, Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the list as an argument then unpack it to a tuple later:

Like this:

```
def computeOverlap(self, target, pos, temp_list, pre_words, post_words):
    (defn, examples, wordnetints) = temp_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
def computeOverlap(self, target, pos, defn , examples, wordnetints, pre_words, post_words):
    context_overlap = 0
    def_overlap = 0
    consecutive_overlap = 0
```

Comment: I tried the same but when I call the computeOverlap function, it gives the below error -

TypeError: computeOverlap() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'pre_words' and 'post_words' (attached new error image)



This is the repository that i'm trying to replicate - 
https://github.com/sgovindgari/cs4740nlp/blob/master/proj02/dictionaryWSD.py

Comment: in your argument you need to pass some words when you call function like test or other

Comment: you can try that `computeOverlap('target word','other','other')`like that